# Debugging Sanity exec with VS Code

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, sanity

I'm using Sanity (sanity.io headless CMS) and doing some data migration with the CLI.

How do I (or, is it at all possible) to some how attach the vscode debugger and stop at breakpoints in migration scripts. I'm running the following cli migration script: `sanity exec migrate.js --with-user-token`. I would like to stop at breakpoints in migrate.js?

I've managed debugging console apps run with node but don't know if it is possible to get the debugger to engage when starting the script with `sanity exec ..`. Stepping through the code is such a great way to find bugs and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was ultimately unsuccessful with debugging the `sanity exec` command, but after reworking the script I got most of the same stuff done with normal node debugging.

- I `import`-ed `client from '@sanity/client'`.
- Made access-tokens to the projects I wished to write to or read drafts from.
- Added appropriate launch-config and,
- Ran the node v14.2.0 normal debugger from vscode and step through my script with breakpoints.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple different ways of debugging the Sanity CLI. I haven't tried your approach before, though.

If you are up for it, you could clone the [OS repository](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity). That would probably make things easier for you. If you're using VS Code, then you could use this launch configuration to run the CLI with the debugger attached:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch CLI",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/@sanity/cli/bin/entry.js",
    "args": [
        "exec",
        "migrate.js",
        "--with-user-token"
    ]
}
```

You will have to run `npm run build` first in order to generate the `entry.js` file.

**EDIT:** If you want to run commands that requires a Studio context, you can run the `symlinkDependencies.js` script. An example of this can be this:

```
node symlinkDependencies.js "/<path>/<to>/<your>/<studio>/<folder>" --all
```

This will create symlinks between your Studio instance and the Sanity monorepo. You will have to run `npm run watch` in the monorepo as well. That way you can edit the code in the monorepo and the commands you run will contain your changes.

---

Another thing you could try is adding an environment variable `DEBUG=*`. This will output debug information when running a CLI command. If you are on a Mac, you could simply run `DEBUG=* sanity exec migrate.js --with-user-token`. If you are on Windows, open PowerShell and run this: `$env:DEBUG=*`. This sets an environment variable for this PowerShell session only. You can then run your command.

For your exact question, I guess you could try with this configuration:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch CLI",
    "program": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/entry.js",
    "args": [
        "exec",
        "migrate.js",
        "--with-user-token"
    ]
}
```

or something like that. I haven't tried this approach myself.

Comment: Ok good, I tried to clone the repository and was able to `npm run build` it. But when running the debugger I get "@sanity/core not installed in current project - run sanity install". Tried installing and "init" on several levels. How do I get both a Sanity project context and cloned repo?

Comment: Ah, yes. I don't have a debug setup for that scenario. You will have to run the script in the repository called `symlinkDependencies`. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Getting close, I can feel it ,'-) I was able to run _build_, _symlinkDependencies_ and _watch_ in the downloaded repository. But debugging that one still complains it's outside a Sanity context. Debugging my Sanity instance with a slightly modified launch `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=27919 node_modules\@sanity\cli\bin\entry.js exec migrate.js --with-user-token` attaches fine and returns no error, but does not hit any breakpoints and then disconnects again.

Can you spot my mistake?

Comment: I don't really know what is going on when using symlinks. I have this exact same issue when debugging, but it should be possible to make it work. Not sure how to go on from here.